# Center a vertical span within an a element

Tags: html, css

I have a layout that looks sort of like a bookshelf, [see my jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/pxhjvuhv/). The bookshelf is responsive so no fixed widths. The issue I'm faced with is that I cannot center the text within the panels, "horizontally" within the books sides. It's extra tricky since the text is transformed to be displayed vertically. Does anyone have any ideas of how to make this work?

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel">
  <a href="#first">
    <span>first</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.panel {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}
.panel a {
  text-align: right;
  background: green;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.panel a span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: -300px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 easy options, with either `display`:`flex` or `table` :

---

display:table example:

```css
body,
html,
.panel-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.panel-wrapper {
  display: table;
  border-collape: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  background: white;
}
.panel {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;/* you have five here*/
}
.panel a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;/*includes padding and borders */
  height: 100%;
  width: 75%;/* each is 15% width */
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.panel a:before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;/*inline  content will vertical-align middle aside it */
}
.panel a span {
  display: inline-block;/* triggers transform*/
  color: white;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-wrapper">
  <div class="panel"><a href="#first"><span>first</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="panel"><a href="#second"><span>second</span></a>
  </div>

  <div class="panel"><a href="#third"><span>third</span></a>
  </div>

  <div class="panel"><a href="#fourth"><span>fourth</span></a>
  </div>

  <div class="panel"><a href="#fifth"><span>fifth</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/JGEbLX

---

or flex:

```css
body,
html,
.panel-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.panel {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}
.panel a {
  text-align: right;
  background: green;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  ;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.panel a span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-wrapper">
  <div class="panel"><a href="#first"><span>first</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="panel"><a href="#second"><span>second</span></a>
  </div>

  <div class="panel"><a href="#third"><span>third</span></a>
  </div>

  <div class="panel"><a href="#fourth"><span>fourth</span></a>
  </div>

  <div class="panel"><a href="#fifth"><span>fifth</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/obBYyY

Comment: I've noticed you're a big fan of display: flex. Any downside to this approach? Is it cross-browser?

Comment: @LOTUSMS the table display here can be used as IE8 fallback (wich can be said cross-browser for nowdays) this is why i include it . flex is today well implemented :)

Comment: Oh I'm not doubting your answer here. This is an unrelated question, I tried PMing you on your profile to discuss but didn't find a link, so I thought I reached you here

Comment: I've always been curious about display flex.

Comment: @LOTUSMS Oups, sorry, i do not stand so close to my computer and will be away a few hours. there is a few good example on css tricks i believe, else plenty topics here :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flexbox

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
.panel a span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: -300px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 20px;
  position:relative;
  left: 45%;
}
```

See my demo [**here**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZWbQE)  or your [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pxhjvuhv/1/)

You may need a small adjustment at tiny smartphones with a media query, but other than that it works

Add this to the responsive css:

```
@media (max-width: 560px){
  .panel a span {
    left: 25%;
  }
}
```

Comment: The three dots in my code imply the code that is already there lol

Comment: There, that's I mean

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to your code :

```
.panel a{
       position:relative;
    }

.panel a span {
      position:absolute;
      left:40%;
       /* top:50%; */
    }
```

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bmldas132/h5em0pv9/)

Answer (score -2):

I f you want center the text vertically use the below property below the `text-align: center` in `.panel a span` make the text in corner center of a panel

```
.panel a span {
    text-align: center;
}
```

and if you want center text in the middle of the panel not in corner

```
.panel a span {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -260px;
}
```

Comment: he should then first delete the width and negative margins used ;)